# Is it sin to criticize Hinduism?

Tags: sin, allowed

Is it sin to criticize Hinduism?
Can one find faults in the Vedas and upanishades, or even criticize the *guru* for something the Student doesn't agree with.

---

By criticize I don't mean to mock or to make fun of religion.

> Criticize : indicate the faults of (someone or something) in a disapproving way.

Comment: Criticism itself is a sort of sin, be it for anything coz it will lead to negative emotions and negative emotions can lead to some unwanted actions that will impact your karma. Just go with the flow! Better option would be questioning or open minded debate!

Comment: @Just_Do_It "*Better option would be questioning or open minded debate!*" in debate you criticize others opinions or argument(s) until you are convinced or you can't bring a better argument to refute others point. **Debate is criticizesim**

Comment: @Just_Do_It it is like an atheist saying Hinduism supports *by birth cast system* and a hindu has to bring verses from the scriptures to refute his claim or understanding. Here Atheist is not mocking Hinduism he is criticizeing Hinduism for something he doesn't agree apon

Comment: It is fine to disagree with the guru, as this story from the brihadaranyaka upanishad demonstrates - https://upanishads.org.in/stories/the-colloquy-of-king-ajatashatru-the-proud-balaki

Comment: There are many instances in the Ramayana when Lakshmana criticizes "Hinduism". It is treated as part of natural debates.

Answer (score 4):

Criticizing Vedas is a sin that is equal to one of the major sins of Hinduism viz:- drinking Sura.

> Manu Smriti 11.56. Forgetting the Veda, **reviling the Vedas**, giving
> false evidence, slaying a friend, eating forbidden food, or
> (swallowing substances) unfit for food, are six (offences) equal to
> drinking Sura.

Whether criticizing is a sin must be depending on the context when it was done, but Manu mentions it as one of the vices particularly for the King.

> 7.48. Tale-bearing, violence, treachery, envy, slandering, (unjust) seizure of property, reviling, and assault are the eightfold set (of
> vices) produced by wrath.

A disciple criticizing the Guru, even if it's "fair", is severely condemned in all Hindu scriptures, including the Tantras.

> Manu 2.201. By censuring (his teacher), though justly, he will become
> (in his next birth) an ass, by falsely defaming him, a dog; he who
> lives on his teacher’s substance, will become a worm, and he who is
> envious (of his merit), a (larger) insect

Comment: But if I respectfully criticize the guru, why is it a sin. Like I read a verse in the Vedas that according to my interpretation it is dualistic(nature of universe) but the guru says it is pluralistic I disagree with him and debated about the verse.

Comment: reviling doesn't mean to criticize in respectful way. It means to criticize in an abusive way.

Comment: **The best example is my comments I am criticizing you**

Comment: "But if I respectfully criticize the guru, why is it a sin" --- I don't know. But scriptures don't allow such a behaviour from the disciple. "reviling doesn't mean to criticize in respectful way. It means to criticize in an abusive way" --- Yes. I know that. But that's all I could find reference for. I can't say if criticizing the Vedas in a polite manner is acceptable or not. @DarkKnight